# Как поменять цвет у ImageView

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Имеется класс унаследованный от LinearLayout, в котором среди прочих элементов имеется ImageView.
ImageView задан в виде VectorAsset.
Необходимо после определенного действия пользователя сменить цвет ImageView.
Подскажите как можно это сделать(Сменить цвет). p.s Метода setColor я не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

Есть другой метод у `ImageView`:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorAccent));
```

Другой вариант:

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(imageView.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));
```

Comment: первым делом я его и попробовал, но цвет изображения не изменился.

Comment: @Nikita В смысле "цвет изображения"? Нужно заменить картинку на цвет или Вы маску хотите наложить поверх?

Comment: @Nikita ну было бы хорошо, если бы вы это добавили в вопрос. А так попробуйте указать вторым параметром один из режимов наложения. Например `PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY` или `PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY`, в зависимости от того, какой эффект вы хотите получить.

Comment: уточняю, имеется значок в виде vectorAsset в сером цвете, после некоторого действия пользователя, этот значок должен стать зеленым.Попробовал указать режимы MULTIPLY и OVERLAY, ничего не помогло

Comment: Добавил ещё один вариант.

Answer (score 0):

У меня работает данный код. **Но** мой класс унаследован от **AppCompatActivity**

```
    Resources resources = getResources();
    imageView.setColorFilter(resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

Для работы кода подключал ресурсы.

```
    import android.content.res.Resources;
```

Comment: вероятно, неплохо было бы уточнить, чем ваш ответ отличается от предыдущего. прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin по вашей просьбе изменил ответ, понял что он не совсем подходит к данному вопросу) Но вдруг кто найдет в моем ответе - свой ответ. Так что оставил его